# Populate CI Build in Jira Server using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jira, devops

I installed the Jira plugin to Jenkins and I have been able to perform different step such as searching issues or adding comments.
I am trying to populate the 'CI builds' section on my Jira tickets.

I've seen the 'Update Relevant Jira Issues for All Build Results' checkbox on the plugin but could not find much information on it online. Will this checkbox populate the CI Builds section? If not, what will and what does this check box does?